# Address sanitizing Boost.Python modules

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, address-sanitizer

My project includes a large C++ library and Python bindings (via Boost.Python).  The test suite is mostly written on top of the Python bindings, and I would like to run it with sanitizers, starting with ASAN.

I'm running macOS (10.13.1 FWIW, but I had the problem with previous versions too), and I can't seem to find a way to run ASAN on Python modules (I very much doubt this is related to Boost.Python, I suppose it's the same with other techniques).

Here is a simple Python module:

```
// hello_ext.cc
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
  auto* res = new char[100];
  std::strcpy(res, "Hello, world!");
  delete [] res;
  return res;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("greet", greet);
}
```

here is the Makefile I used, made for MacPorts:

```
// Makefile
CXX = clang++-mp-4.0
CXXFLAGS = -g -std=c++14 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
CPPFLAGS = -isystem/opt/local/include $$($(PYTHON_CONFIG) --includes)
LDFLAGS = -L/opt/local/lib
PYTHON = python3.5
PYTHON_CONFIG = python3.5-config
LIBS = -lboost_python3-mt $$($(PYTHON_CONFIG) --ldflags)

all: hello_ext.so

hello_ext.so: hello_ext.cc
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

check: all
        $(ENV) $(PYTHON) -c 'import hello_ext; print(hello_ext.greet())'

clean:
        -rm -f hello_ext.so
```

Without asan, everything works well (well, too well actually...).  But with ASAN, I hit `LD_PRELOAD` like issues:

```
$ make check
python -c 'import hello_ext; print(hello_ext.greet())'
==19013==ERROR: Interceptors are not working. This may be because AddressSanitizer is loaded too late (e.g. via dlopen). Please launch the executable with:
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
"interceptors not installed" && 0make: *** [check] Abort trap: 6
```

Okay, let's do that: define DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES

```
$ DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib \
  python -c 'import hello_ext; print(hello_ext.greet())'
==19023==ERROR: Interceptors are not working. This may be because AddressSanitizer is loaded too late (e.g. via dlopen). Please launch the executable with:
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
"interceptors not installed" && 0zsh: abort      DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES= python -c 'import hello_ext; print(hello_ext.greet())'
```

Let's be suspicious about SIP, so *I have disabled SIP here*, and let's resolve the symlinks:

```
$ DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib \
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -c 'import hello_ext; print(hello_ext.greet())'
==19026==ERROR: Interceptors are not working. This may be because AddressSanitizer is loaded too late (e.g. via dlopen). Please launch the executable with:
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
"interceptors not installed" && 0zsh: abort      DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=  -c 'import hello_ext; print(hello_ext.greet())'
```

What's the right way to do that?  I have also tried to load libasan with `ctypes.PyDLL`, and even with `sys.setdlopenflags(os.RTLD_NOW | os.RTLD_GLOBAL)` I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I finally managed to get this to work:

```
$ libasan=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
$ python=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
$ DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=$libasan $python -c 'import hello_ext; print(hello_ext.greet())'
=================================================================
==70859==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60b000002770 at pc 0x000108c2ef60 bp 0x7ffee6fe8c20 sp 0x7ffee6fe83c8
READ of size 2 at 0x60b000002770 thread T0
    #0 0x108c2ef5f in wrap_strlen (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x14f5f)
    #1 0x109a8d939 in PyUnicode_FromString (Python:x86_64+0x58939)
[...]
```

What changed?  Nothing in the compilation chain, just the invocation.

Let `PYDIR=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5`: previously I was calling `$PYDIR/bin/python3.5` (because `/opt/local/bin/python3.5` is a symlink to it), now I call `$PYDIR/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`.

To understand what was going on, I ran `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=$libasan python3.5`, and looked for its open files

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
  900 ttys000    0:07.96 -zsh
70897 ttys000    0:00.11 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
53528 ttys001    0:05.14 -zsh
  920 ttys002    0:10.28 -zsh
$ lsof -p 70897
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
Python  70897 akim  cwd    DIR    1,4        480 8605949500 /Users/akim/src/lrde/vcsn/experiment/sanitizer
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4      12988 8591019542 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4    2643240 8591012758 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4     107524 8590943656 /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4    2097528 8590888556 /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4      20224 8591016920 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4     326996 8591375651 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/readline/gnureadline.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4     603008 8605907803 /opt/local/lib/libncurses.6.dylib
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4     837248 8606849556 /usr/lib/dyld
Python  70897 akim  txt    REG    1,4 1155837952 8606860187 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h
Python  70897 akim    0u   CHR   16,0  0t2756038        667 /dev/ttys000
Python  70897 akim    1u   CHR   16,0  0t2756038        667 /dev/ttys000
Python  70897 akim    2u   CHR   16,0  0t2756038        667 /dev/ttys000
```

Obviously libasan is not here, and that's the whole problem.  However, I also noticed that `ps` was referring to another Python than the one I ran (and, of course, it's part of the open files).

It turns out that there are several Python executables in this directory: `$PYDIR/bin/python3.5` and `$PYDIR/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`, and the first one, in one way or another, bounces to the second.  If I run the second with `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=$libasan`

```
$ lsof -p 71114
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
Python  71114 akim  cwd    DIR    1,4       480 8605949500 /Users/akim/src/lrde/vcsn/experiment/sanitizer
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4     12988 8591019542 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4   3013168 8604479549 /opt/local/libexec/llvm-4.0/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4   2643240 8591012758 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4    107524 8590943656 /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4   2097528 8590888556 /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4     20224 8591016920 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4    326996 8591375651 /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/readline/gnureadline.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4    603008 8605907803 /opt/local/lib/libncurses.6.dylib
Python  71114 akim  txt    REG    1,4    837248 8606849556 /usr/lib/dyld
Python  71114 akim    0u   CHR   16,0 0t2781894        667 /dev/ttys000
Python  71114 akim    1u   CHR   16,0 0t2781894        667 /dev/ttys000
Python  71114 akim    2u   CHR   16,0 0t2781894        667 /dev/ttys000
```

\o/  libasan is there!  So apparently, the first Python calls the second one, and `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` is not forwarded.

I currently have no idea why there are two Pythons.  It does not seem to be specific to MacPorts, as it's also the case for Apple's Python.

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
$ ls -l bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      7 10 déc 08:17 bin/python -> python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     14 10 déc 08:17 bin/python-config -> python2-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      9 10 déc 08:17 bin/python2 -> python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     16 10 déc 08:17 bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  43104  1 déc 21:42 bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   1818 16 jul 02:20 bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      8 10 déc 08:17 bin/pythonw -> pythonw2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     10 10 déc 08:17 bin/pythonw2 -> pythonw2.7
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  43104  1 déc 21:42 bin/pythonw2.7
$ ls -l Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  51744  1 déc 21:48 Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Comment: it makes so much sense in retrospect! excellent detective work sir! have an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a less than ideal answer, but it should provide you with what you need.

I'm proposing you make an Xcode project to build everything (yes, I know you want to use make, that comes later)

Assuming you already know how to get a Xcode project building everything I'll skip ahead to enabling Address Sanitizer:

`Product` -> `Scheme` -> `Edit Scheme` will open this window:
[image: Edit Scheme]

Check the boxes for Address Sanitizer. You should only have to do this for your main Application. In my experience all the dependancies will be built appropriately.

Next Build the main application target. We will need to examine the compiler and linker invocations so we can copy any necessary flags/steps to the make files.

[image: Build Output]

I've circled the 2 relevant buttons to get the output. The rightmost button will expand the compiler invocation used to build.

[image: relevant output]

This shot shows both a save button (it may be easier to examine in another program) and *some* of the relevant flags used for building. You will have to examine the output for *all* targets (dependancies) to get a clear picture.

Hope this helps. FWIW the project in my example has a custom Python module written in C++ (directly using libPython, not Boost) so I know you can use Asan on those even using the System supplied Python frameworks.

Comment: Hi Brad.  I have tried to add `-D_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ASAN` to the MWE in my question, but to no avail.  It still does not work.

Comment: @akim I didn't mean to suggest that was all you were missing. that is _truncated_ output. I meant for you to examine your own project output. It wont do you any good unless you have your own Xcode project that _works_ with Asan. Do that first then the rest should be easy.

Comment: So I have created an Xcode project (that took me quite a while, as I'm not using it), and enabled asan, etc.  And the result is exactly the same: I cannot load that module into Python because ASAN loaded too late.

Comment: @akim I cant comment on your Xcode project (unless its on github or something), but have you tried statically linking Asan? eg `-static-libasan` if its compiled into the binary it should bypass this issue.

Comment: No such option with more Clangs.  As [documented](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#limitations): Static linking is not supported.

Comment: @akim "not supported" doesnt mean "doesnt work". I statically link with asan all the time when I build with GCC: https://gist.github.com/kwk/4171e37f4bcdf7705329

Comment: I do mean that I ran the command, and clang told me `clang: error: unknown argument: '-static-libasan'`. The command was: `clang++-mp-4.0 -isystem/opt/local/include $(python3.5-config --includes) -g -std=c++14 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -L/opt/local/lib -shared -o hello_ext.so hello_ext.cc -lboost_python3-mt $(python3.5-config --ldflags) -static-libasan`.  And GCC is not an option for me: my system compiler is Clang, not GCC.

Comment: And sorry for the typo above, instead of "No such option with more Clangs", read "No such option with modern Clangs".

Comment: @akim I'm sorry it sounds like you've wasted your time on my suggestion. When you figure it out please post the answer and I will likely delete mine. Until then this still may prove useful for others in other contexts.

Comment: Hi Brad.  Sorry if I sounded like that, that was not my intention.  I do appreciate that you took some time to teach me your approach.

Comment: @akim you are welcome. Since this answer received upvotes I will leave it so that it may prove helpful to others in the future. Glad you found an answer.